# How to trigger on empty or whitespace

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have the following button in my WPF grid:

```
<Button FontSize="18" Height="32" Content="Add Module" Name="AddModuleButton" Click="AddModuleButton_Click">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=val_Name, Path=Text}" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
                    <Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="false" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

As you can see, the button is enabled if the text is not empty. But what I really want is to enable it if the textbox is empty or only whitespace.

Can anyone tell me how to do this in WPF XAML

Comment: You could try a multibinding or multiple bindings. For the value, you can provide another static class and property containing all your characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three approaches come to mind.

1. (View)Model state: Having a boolean property for that in an object and just [binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) it.

   ```
    public bool CanAddModule { get { return !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Text); } }
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _text)
            {
                _text = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Text");
                OnPropertyChanged("CanAddModule"); // Notify dependent get-only property
            }
        }
    }
   ```

   ```
   <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" .../>
   <Button IsEnabled="{Binding CanAddModule}" .../>
   ```
2. An extension of the above would be binding the [`Button.Command`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommandsource.command.aspx), the command internally has a `CanExecute` which serves this function. If that function is false the `Button` gets disabled. You need to raise the `CanExecuteChanged` event in every property that changed on which the function is dependent.
3. [Converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx): Add a converter to the binding.

   ```
    // In converter class
    public object Convert(object value, ...)
    {
         var input = (string)value;
         return String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input);
    }
   ```

   ```
    <!--Resources-->
    <vc:IsNullOrWhiteSpaceConverter x:Key="NWSConv" />
   ```

   ```
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text,
                                   ElementName=val_Name,
                                   Converter={StaticResource NWSConv}}"
                 Value="false">
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution that isn't a complete answer to this question but one that will work as a solution of my problem.

I added a TextChanged event on my TextBox:

```
TextBox lTextBox = (TextBox)sender;
string lCurrText = lTextBox.Text;
string lNewText = Regex.Replace(lCurrText, @"\W", "");
lTextBox.Text = lNewText;
```

It doesn't allow whitespaces now.